# SharePoint 2010 creating a field that checks against a limit

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, create-fields

I'm creating a site where people can submit requests to be approved to take a course. Each person is given $4000 per calendar year to use. The request form has a box called course cost where the person enters the course amount.

How can I make it that every time a person makes a request the system keeps a tally that checks to make sure the person has the money available. e.g john wants to take a class he has $500 left in his account. He enters $1000 in the course cost box on the form. I want it to turn red or get block with a message "not enough funds left"

Comment: is the list you have created a custom list??

Comment: Use workflow to sum the values and update to a new column, create a validation on the new column, if the value of the new column is greater then $4000 , then alert a message.


Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fdbf2f52-93b7-424d-b150-443939d47edc/sharepoint-workflow-sum-the-values-and-update-to-a-new-list-name-as-condition?forum=sharepointcustomization

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do some custom logic on your form using js or server side code. First query the list for all approved requests in given year. Use the value to populate label on form That will give you the amount spend. Then it is simple check in js that the number entered is lower than the funds left for that person in the tax year.